# How to say “dealer” in Spanish when playing cards?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

Which term is correct for "dealer" in Spanish in a card game?

> Repartidor(a)
>   Dador(a)
>   [something else?]

Are these terms interchangeable? IS one preferred over others?

Answer (score 5):

El español admite la voz francesa [crupier](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BO5xwEY)

> Del fr. croupier.
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona contratada en los casinos para dirigir el juego, repartir las cartas, controlar las apuestas, etc.

(y en [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crupier))

> El crupier o croupier es también llamado tallador o **repartidor** de casino

Un *crupier* es un profesional, pero te entenderían perfectamente si usases el término para alguien que realiza la labor de una forma no profesional.

Dicho esto, se puede usar perfectamente [repartidor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W0epfGg) para referirse a la persona que durante toda o parte de la partida realiza la acción repartir, aunque suena raro. Lo más normal (lo que puedes ver en las instrucciones de un juego) es decir `el jugador encargado de repartir`, más que "el repartidor".

Por lo menos en el español de España nadie usa "[dador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BpGLhBy)" con ese significado.

Comment: También he visto `el jugador que reparte [...]`. ¡Buena respuesta!

Comment: Walen, sí, cierto, y eso me ha recordado que en algunos juegos sí se nombra a algunos jugadores dependiendo de su rol (a veces dependiendo del turno), por ejemplo "quién es mano"? "En la [jerga del mus](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mus) se denomina **mano** al jugador que se encuentra a la derecha **del que reparte**, [...] **postre** al jugador que reparte las cartas y que es el último en hablar." No se me ocurre ahora ningún juego en que el jugador que reparte en cada momento tenga un nombre.